# mysql field name contain backtick

Tags: mysql

I want to create table with a field surrounded by backticks

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (`id` INT);
```

I have tried:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (``id`` INT);
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Don't do that please.

Comment: use \' slash before that

Comment: Just when I thought I heard it all

Comment: it's not a best practice, but you can create like that CREATE TABLE t1 ("'id'" INT);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) (emphasis mine):

> Identifier quote characters can be included within an identifier if you quote the identifier. If the character to be included within the identifier is the same as that used to quote the identifier itself, then you need to **double the character**.

In your case:

````
CREATE TABLE t1 (```id``` INT);
````